# R shiny: Create bucket list that automatically deletes inputted contents

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a `bucket_list` that serves as a trash can, so as to delete each item that is dragged into it.

Am I right in attempting to use `observeEvent` that upon `input` of the delete bucket? I can't get the delete bucket to update empty.

Please see the following example:

```
library(shiny)
library(sortable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("groups")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  derp = (c(1:5))
  
  output$groups = renderUI({bucket_list(
    header = "",
    group_name = "rank_groups",
    orientation = "horizontal",
    
    add_rank_list(
      text = h5("Group 1"),
      input_id = "Group1",
      labels = derp),
    
    add_rank_list(
      text = h5("Delete"),
      input_id = "delete"))})

 
observeEvent(input$delete,(output$delete = NULL))
   
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thank you

Comment: Does [this example](https://rstudio.github.io/sortable/articles/cloning.html) help?

Comment: Yes. Thanks, @Ben.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted. Thanks, @Ben, for the direction.

```
library(shiny)
library(sortable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("groups")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  derp = (c(1:5))
  
  output$groups = renderUI({bucket_list(
    header = "",
    group_name = "rank_groups",
    orientation = "horizontal",
    
    add_rank_list(
      text = h5("Group 1"),
      input_id = "Group1",
      labels = derp),
    
    add_rank_list(
      text = h5("Delete"),
      input_id = "delete",
      options = sortable_options(
        onAdd = htmlwidgets::JS("function (evt) { this.el.removeChild(evt.item); }")
      )
        ))})
  
 
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```